# Python: List index out of range when performing a query using osmapi

Tags: python, openstreetmap

Hi I am new to `osmapi` and python too. I was writing a script to perform some queries using `osmapi` until I got this error and the data seems to work on this link https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/77517260, and same for the xml response https://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/way/77517260.

When I test for another way ID it works, but this id `77517260` doesn't, here is the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osmapi/OsmApi.py in _OsmResponseToDom(self, response, tag, single)
   2060             all_data = osm_dom.getElementsByTagName(tag)
-> 2061             first_element = all_data[0]
   2062         except (xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError, IndexError) as e:

IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

XmlResponseInvalidError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-79d93245d84a> in <module>
----> 1 way = api.NodeWays(77517260)

~/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osmapi/OsmApi.py in NodeWays(self, NodeId)
    513         uri = "/api/0.6/node/%d/ways" % NodeId
    514         data = self._get(uri)
--> 515         ways = self._OsmResponseToDom(data, tag="way")
    516         result = []
    517         for way in ways:

~/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osmapi/OsmApi.py in _OsmResponseToDom(self, response, tag, single)
   2062         except (xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError, IndexError) as e:
   2063             raise XmlResponseInvalidError(
-> 2064                 "The XML response from the OSM API is invalid: %r" % e
   2065             )
   2066 

XmlResponseInvalidError: The XML response from the OSM API is invalid: IndexError('list index out of range',)
```

my python code:

```py
import osmapi as osm
api = osm.OsmApi()
way = api.NodeWays(77517260)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First - you should pass url and credentials in constructor:

`api = osm.OsmApi(api="https://api.openstreetmap.org", username="username", password="secret")`

Next -`api/0.6/way/{id}` - maybe you are looking for `WayGet` method.

Code:

`import osmapi as osm
api = osm.OsmApi(api="https://api.openstreetmap.org", username="username", password="secret")
way = api.WayGet(77517260)`

Comment: Thanks @norbeq for the answer didn't know I should mention the credential when using `osmapi`